# Projection onto the set of Orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, projection

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and denote the set of Orthogonal matrices by
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{O}_{n} = \left\lbrace Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \colon QQ^{T} = \mathbb{I}_{n} \right\rbrace .
\end{equation}

> What is an efficient way to find the projection of an arbitrary matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ onto $\mathcal{O}_{n}$.

One approach I can find is to compute the Singular Value Decomposition of $M$, namely,
\begin{equation}
M = U \Sigma V^{T} .
\end{equation}
Then we have
\begin{equation}
Q = UV^{T} .
\end{equation}

Is there any other approach besides this SVD?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215359/showing-that-matrix-q-uvt-is-the-nearest-orthogonal-matrix-to-a

Comment: Thanks @BrianBorchers. What I'm looking for is another approach than SVD

Comment: Create two orthogonal matrices $Q_L,Q_R$ by QR'ing two random n x n matrices. Then use the formula $M\approx Q_LQ_L^TMQ_RQ_R^T$ to find the projection. This is essentially a change of basis on both the row and column spaces. Unfortunately QR costs the same asymptotically as SVD; orthogonal matrix generation is always gonna be expensive

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts on **a particular case** of low-rank matrices ($k=\text{rank}(M)\ll n)$. Here, I can suggest some economical version of SVDs:

**Rand-SVD**

Here is the [R package documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RGeode/versions/0.1.0/topics/randSVD) that also contains references for canonical papers of V. Rokhlin and P. Martinsson on this topic. That should reduce the complexity to $\mathcal O(nk^2+k^3)$ as opposed to $\mathcal O(n^3)$ for dense SVD.

**ACA-based**

1. Find (or if you start with one) low-rank representation of matrix $M=AB^T$, where $A,B\in\mathbb R^{n\times k}$. This might come from "physics" (if the matrix $M$ comes from the discretization) or, by using a pure linear algebra approach like [ACA (adaptive cross approximation)](https://doi.org/10.1007/PL00005410) (usually at $\mathcal O(nk^2)$).
2. Find QR of $A$ and $B$ in $\mathcal O(nk^2)$ resulting in $A=Q_AR_A$, $B=Q_BR_B$, where $Q_A, Q_B\in\mathbb R^{n\times k}$ and $R_A,R_B\in\mathbb R^{k\times k}$, upper triangular.
3. Find $P = R_A R_B$ in $\mathcal O(k^3)$.
4. Compute SVD of $P$ in $\mathcal O(k^3)$ resulting in $P=U_P\Sigma V_P^T$. Here, $U_P, \Sigma, V_P \in \mathbb R^{k\times k}$, $\Sigma$ - diagonal. Notice, $\Sigma$ is the matrix of singular values not only for $P$, but for the original $M$, as well.
5. Find $U=Q_AU_P$ and $V=Q_BV_P$ in $\mathcal O(nk^2)$.
6. Now you have an SVD of $M=U\Sigma V^T$ in total of $\mathcal O(nk^2+k^3)$ operations.

Comment: thanks! so unless we know more about the structure of our matrix, otherwise there is no algorithm more efficient than SVD in general right?

Comment: @mortal At least, I am not aware of such an algorithm in general case. There might be some other randomized orthogonalization algorithm that gives decent results/complexity for a general case (or wider subclass of matrices), but I do not know that. Also, the origin of the matrix might be of interest, as some algorithms require and can benefit from the "physics" rather than be purely algebraical.

Comment: (by a wider subclass, I meant, compared to low-rank matrices)

Comment: thanks for your kind opinion. I will have a look more on my matrices